# How do put a code well in my website?

Tags: html

I'm currently creating a website and I need to show an example of code on the page. simply putting it within a p obviously doesn't work, as the tags do not display. Is there anyway to get them to display on the webpage?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: Assuming you want to present some html tags on your webpage: you also need to convert your code to [html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) first. What technology are you using to build your website?

Comment: I use Notepad++ to program pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can put code in [`<code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) tags (if what you're displaying is in a programming language) just to get something going quickly.  If what you're displaying is Markup (HTML), you'll have to replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.

You can also look at tools like [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) if you want your code to be more readable.

Comment: `<code>` doesn't make tags display as text.

Comment: @Quentin You're right. I didn't realize that what the OP was displaying is markup. Thanks.